Unable to start Dynamic Analysis
I use the docker to install MobSF successfully on MAC with M1.
I can install the app on the Genymotion ,but when using MobSF for dynamic analysis, errors happens:

[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:32 - Creating Dynamic Analysis Environment for com.medapp.man
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:35 - ADB Restarted
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:35 - Waiting for 2 seconds...
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:37 - Connecting to Android host.docker.internal:6555
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:37 - Waiting for 2 seconds...
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:39 - Restarting ADB Daemon as root
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:39 - Waiting for 2 seconds...
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:41 - Reconnecting to Android Device
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:41 - Waiting for 2 seconds...
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:43 - Found Genymotion x86 Android VM
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:43 - Remounting
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:43 - Performing System check
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:43 - Android API Level identified as 30
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:43 - Android Version identified as 11.0
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:43 - Environment MobSFyed Check
(trapped) error reading bcrypt version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/passlib/handlers/bcrypt.py", line 620, in _load_backend_mixin
version = _bcrypt.about.version
AttributeError: module 'bcrypt' has no attribute 'about'
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:47 - Installing MobSF RootCA
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:47 - Starting HTTPS Proxy on 1337
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:47 - Enabling ADB Reverse TCP on 1337
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:47 - Setting Global Proxy for Android VM
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:47 - Installing APK - com.medapp.man
[INFO] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:47 - Removing Global Proxy for Android VM
[ERROR] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:47 - This APK cannot be installed. Is this APK compatible the Android VM/Emulator?
adb install failed
[ERROR] 27/Apr/2024 03:36:47 - Internal Server Error: /android_dynamic/bb28781590009a023645e53c4f375f1f

I try to do what I can do ,but it failed
